# Consumir web service (WSDL) em PHP

Tags: php, web-service, wsdl

Não tenho muita experiência prática com web services. Preciso utilizar alguns métodos deste: https://epfweb.fakepath.com.br/WCF/SvcContratos.svc?wsdl

Alguém poderia me ajudar em como realizar a conexão com ele em PHP e obter o retorno?

Por exemplo: Há um método chamado **GerarToken()** que recebe 3 parâmetros: **DfUsuario** (Tipo: string), **DsSenha** (Tipo: string), **IdTipoConsulta** (Tipo: TipoConsulta).

Como eu poderia utilizar o web service para acessar esse método e obter o retorno dele (o token, nesse caso) em uma variável?

Answer (score 1):

Tente esse código:

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient('https://epfweb.fakepath.com.br/WCF/SvcContratos.svc?wsdl');
$function = 'GerarToken';
$arguments= array('GerarToken' => array(
    'DsUsuario'      => 'Usuario',
    'DsSenha'        => 'Senha'
));
 
 
$result = $client->__soapCall($function, $arguments);
echo 'Response: ';
print_r($result);
 
?>
```

Pode ser necessário instalar a extensão `SoapClient`.

[PHP: How do I install soap extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509143/php-how-do-i-install-soap-extension)

**Não deixe de ver:**

[Utilizando SOAP com PHP](https://ajuda.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/Utilizando_SOAP_com_PHP)

Comment: Obtive esse erro de retorno:


Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [a:InternalServiceFault] The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error. For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.

Testei com outro webservice (de previsao do tempo) e funcionou.

Comment: É provável que o webservice do Safra exija uma autenticação, seria interessante você solicitar ao Safra a documentação do webservice.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient('https://epfweb.fakepath.com.br/WCF/SvcContratos.svc?wsdl');
$arguments = [
    'GerarToken' => [
        'objLogin' => [
             'DsUsuario' => 'Usuario',
             'DsSenha'   => 'Senha'
        ]   
    ]
];

$result = $client->__soapCall('GerarToken', $arguments);
echo 'Response: ';
print_r($result);

?>
```